# Principal Component Analysis throws constant/zero column Error

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to run a PCA on the "training1" data set created below:

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling); data(AlzheimerDisease); library(caret)

adData <- data.frame(diagnosis, predictors)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = adData$diagnosis, p = .75)[[1]]
training <- adData[inTrain, ]
keep <- subset(data.frame(x = substr(as.character(colnames(training)), 1, 2), y = c(1:ncol(training))), x == "IL")
training1 <- cbind(training[, c(keep[1, 2]:keep[nrow(keep), 2])], training[c("diagnosis")])
```

Then, when I run the following function:

```
preProc <- preProcess(log10(training1[, -13]+1), method = "pca", pcaComp = 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning in preProcess.default(log10(training1[, -13] + 1), method = "pca",  :
  Std. deviations could not be computed for: IL_1alpha, IL_3
Error in prcomp.default(x[, method$pca, drop = FALSE], scale = TRUE, retx = FALSE) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

However, I then run run the following two functions to prove that standard deviations can be calculated for the two variables it says that it can't calculate them for:

```
sd(training1$IL_1alpha)
[1] 0.4056147
sd(training1$IL_3)
[1] 0.5235212
```

And then run the following function to prove that I do not have any variables with a zero variance.

```
nsv <- nearZeroVar(training1, saveMetrics = TRUE)
> print(nsv)
              freqRatio percentUnique zeroVar   nzv
IL_11          1.250000    29.4820717   FALSE FALSE
IL_13          1.052632     6.7729084   FALSE FALSE
IL_16          1.117647    21.9123506   FALSE FALSE
IL_17E         1.238095    16.7330677   FALSE FALSE
IL_1alpha      1.208333    23.1075697   FALSE FALSE
IL_3           1.066667    24.7011952   FALSE FALSE
IL_4           1.315789    19.1235060   FALSE FALSE
IL_5           1.000000    19.5219124   FALSE FALSE
IL_6           1.000000    20.3187251   FALSE FALSE
IL_6_Receptor  1.041667    21.5139442   FALSE FALSE
IL_7           1.611111    18.7250996   FALSE FALSE
IL_8           1.000000    22.3107570   FALSE FALSE
diagnosis      2.637681     0.7968127   FALSE FALSE
```

It seems like other people's issues with PCA in R were around zero variance columns, but since I can prove that I don't have that issue here, any ideas what may be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have the rep to comment, so posting as an answer, but after running your code, in particular this line:

```
 log10(training1[, -13]+1)
```

returns `NaN` values in some columns (`IL_1alpha` and `IL_3` actually):

```
 Warning messages:
 1: In lapply(X = x, FUN = .Generic, ...) : NaNs produced
```

So that seems to be the source of the error. Maybe you shouldn't take log's of negative numbers and think of other transformation instead (or whether it is necessary at all)?